# In C, how is the main() method initially called?

Tags: c, operating-system

How does a C program get started?

Comment: You do!  You call the main()!  Yes that's right!  Yes you do!

Comment: Who watches the watchers?

Comment: The subject is a statement but the body is a question.

Comment: The CRT initialization code.  Exact details are platform specific.

Comment: Why, Justin, why? It was poetry!

Comment: Wow, the way this question is evolving reminds me of "How do I move the turtle in LOGO?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a C/C++ program how does the system (windows, linux, mac OS X) call the main() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332/in-a-c-c-program-how-does-the-system-windows-linux-mac-os-x-call-the-main)

Answer (score 56):

The operating system calls the `main()` function. Eventually.

The [Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=elf&sektion=5) which many Unix OS's use defines an entry point address and an INIT address. That is where the program begins to run after the OS finishes its `exec()` call. On a Linux system this is `_init` in the `.init` section. After that returns it jumps to the entry point address which is `_start` in the `.text` section.

The C compiler links a standard library to every application which provides these operating system defined initialization and entry points. That library then calls `main()`.

Here is my C source code for the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  puts("Hello world!");
  return 0;
}
```

From `objdump -d`:

```
Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000001000 <_init>:
    1000:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1004:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    1008:   48 8b 05 d9 2f 00 00    mov    0x2fd9(%rip),%rax        # 3fe8 <__gmon_start__>
    100f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
    1012:   74 02                   je     1016 <_init+0x16>
    1014:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
    1016:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    101a:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001060 <_start>:
    1060:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1064:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
    1066:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
    1069:   5e                      pop    %rsi
    106a:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
    106d:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
    1071:   50                      push   %rax
    1072:   54                      push   %rsp
    1073:   4c 8d 05 66 01 00 00    lea    0x166(%rip),%r8        # 11e0 <__libc_csu_fini>
    107a:   48 8d 0d ef 00 00 00    lea    0xef(%rip),%rcx        # 1170 <__libc_csu_init>
    1081:   48 8d 3d c1 00 00 00    lea    0xc1(%rip),%rdi        # 1149 <main>
    1088:   ff 15 52 2f 00 00       callq  *0x2f52(%rip)          # 3fe0 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    108e:   f4                      hlt    
    108f:   90                      nop

0000000000001140 <frame_dummy>:
    1140:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1144:   e9 77 ff ff ff          jmpq   10c0 <register_tm_clones>
```

From `readelf -h` you can see the Entry point address that matches `_start`:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1060
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          17416 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         13
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         36
  Section header string table index: 35
```

From `readelf -d`:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x2dc8 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x11e8
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x3db8
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x3dc0
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x3a0
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x470
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x3c8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              130 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x3fb8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x5e0
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x520
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             192 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x500
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x4f2
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

You can see that INIT is equal to the address of `_init`.

There is a whole array of function pointers in INIT_ARRAY also. See `objdump -s -j .init_array c-test`:

```
c-test:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .init_array:
 3db8 40110000 00000000                    @.......
```

You can see that address 0x3db8 is the same as INIT_ARRAY in the ELF header.

The address 0x1140 (remember little-endian byte layout from 40110000) is the function `frame_dummy` you can see in the disassembly. Which then calls `register_tm_clones` and who knows what else.

The code for initialization is in a set of files named crtbegin.o and crtend.o (and variants of those names). The `__libc_start_main` function is defined in libc.so.6. These libraries are part of GCC. That code does various things necessary for a C program like setting up stdin, stdout, global and static variables and other things.

The following article describes quite well what it does in Linux (taken from an answer below with less votes): http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

I believe someone else's answer already described what Windows does.

Comment: it doesn't call `_init` or any other. it calls the entry point address. it can be anywhere.

Comment: NEEDED libstdc++.so.6? This is not from a C program!

Comment: @Jens: It makes no difference in this instance.

Comment: @ZanLynx How can you tell? How can I tell? Why not simply look at a C program instead? C and C++ are vastly different languages, and program startup is one of the areas where this is visible (e.g. calling constructors).

Comment: @Jens: How can *you* tell, since you don't trust me? Use the objdump -d disassembler to look at the machine code and use readelf -d to view the ELF stuff. Or grab a hex editor and a copy of the ELF spec.

Comment: @ZanLynx I've done all that. I question the validity of proving something for a C++ program when the question is about C. Especially when it is easy to perform the same analysis on a real C program. How hard is it to compile a C program with a C compiler and then run objdump on *that*? You wouldn't demonstrate the same with a FORTRAN program, right? :-)

Answer (score 26):

Eventually it is operating system. Usually there is some medium between real entry point and main function, this is inserted by <strike>compiler</strike> linker.

Some details (related to Windows): There is header in PE file called `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` which has the field `AddressOfEntryPoint`, which is in turn address of the first code byte in the file that will be executed.

Comment: It's not inserted by the compiler, it's inserted by the linker, usually by linking to something like `crt.a(crt.o)` or `crt.lib(crt.obj)`, which usually is part of something like `libc.a` or `c.lib`.

Comment: @ChristianHujer you are right, by compiler I meant well the toolchain.

Comment: you sure about __linker__, I guess what __loader__ does then?

Comment: @roottraveller Linker links. The executable may even never be loaded.

Answer (score 11):

The operating system calls main. There will be an address in the relocatable executable that points at the location of main (See the Unix ABI for more information).

**But**, who calls the operating system?

The central processing unit, on the "RESET" signal, (which is also asserted at power on), will begin looking in some ROM at a given address (say, 0xffff) for its instructions.

Typically there will be some sort of jump instruction out to the BIOS, which gets the memory chips configured, the basic hard drive drivers loaded, etc, etc. Then the Boot Sector of the hard drive is read, and the *next* bootloader is started, which loads the file containing the basic information of how to read, say, an NTFS partition and how to read the kernel file itself.  The kernel environment will be set up, the kernel loaded, and then - *and then!* - the kernel will be jumped to for execution.

After all that hard work has been done, the kernel can then proceed to load our software.

Answer (score 9):

http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2008-04/msg04617.html

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, the link has good information

Comment: @Zack Generally posting a link without some sort of summary here is frowned upon

Answer (score 5):

The operating system calls a function included in the C runtime (CRT) and linked into your executable.  Call this "CRT main."

CRT main does a few things, the two most important of which, at least in C++, are to run through an array of global C++ classes and call their constructors, and to call your main() function and give its return value to the shell.

The Visual C++ CRT main does a few more things, if memory serves.  It configures the memory allocator, important if using the Debug CRT to help find memory leaks or bad accesses.  It also calls main within a [structured exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51(VS.80).aspx) handler that catches bad memory access and other crashes and displays them.

Comment: Even though you are talking about C++ not C, your post is illuminating!

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best information for your question can be found in the below mentioned link
http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html,
the best one I have come across till date.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Note that in addition to the answers already posted, it is also possible for you to call `main` yourself.  Generally this is a bad idea reserved for obfuscated code.

Comment: This isn't legal in C++, by the way - one more way in which C++ isn't a strict superset.