# Who calls the main function in C

Tags: c, linux, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, how is the main() method initially called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469955/in-c-how-is-the-main-method-initially-called)

I want to know, who calls the main function in C.

What is actual use of the main function ( why main is special/necessary ) ?
Can I write a c program with out main function ?

Comment: If you write a program without a main, how do you imagine it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you ask your operating system to run a file, it loads it into memory, and jumps to it starting point (`_start`,etc). At this point, there is an code, that call `main` and then exit (The linker is responsible to this part). If you will write program without `main` function, the linker will give you an error, since it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7):

The `main` function is called, in practice, by the C runtime.

You can write a program without `main` but it *must* have an entry point.  Different operating systems allow you to specify different entry points for your program, but they all serve the same purpose as `main`.  On Windows, you can use `WinMain`.  On Linux you can link without the CRT and define your own `_start` function (but it cannot return!)

A program without an entry point is like a car without wheels: it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Isn't it the other way arround?The program calls and links to C runtime?

Comment: More like a car without start engine, the car is there, it could do everything it's supposed to, but there's nothing that starts the process

Comment: 1) What do you mean by C runtime ?
2) Do you mean if I write a C program which is executing in my OS perfectly .... I can't run it on different OS because different OS have different entry points ???

Comment: @vikram: 1) The C runtime is code provided by the C implementation on your platform. 2) All compliant platforms support `main`, so you if you use `main`, you only have to recompile.  If you use `WinMain`, your program will not run on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: @user384706: No, the C runtime usually calls main.  On Linux, for example, the C runtime provides the `_start` symbol which is the actual entry point for programs.  It is not a function, it cannot return because it does not have a caller.  This allows separation between the C implementation on your platform and the OS kernel.  The kernel doesn't care about your calling conventions so you can use whatever calling conventions you'd like.

Comment: A program without an entry point is like a dynamic library, it has no entry point lmao

Answer (score 0):

Your program (which is series of code bundled inside functions) must have to have a starting point right?

Something must be called first to run the rest.

So, that starting point is `main`, which is called by the parent process in your O/S (what ever that is) and lets your program run

Comment: yah, I know that but when I write

`$./a.out` 

which program I am actually running ?

Comment: You fork a process that calls main (this is an ELF file)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is this: the user of your program calls the main function when they start your application. Have you ever used a command terminal? If you have you will know that you can pass arguments to a command. For example:

```
$ grep word myfile
```

What is going on under the covers is the Terminal looks at what you typed then calls the `main` method of the grep program and passes `[word, myfile]` as the second argument to this method. This is a simplification but I hope it helps.