# Where does the returned value for 'main' function go?

Tags: c, function, return, program-entry-point, return-type

In C, a function **always** returns its value to the calling function and never to itself (**if return type is not void**). Like,

```
int main()
```

But since '**main**' function is **called by the Operating System**, which is **not a function**. So, whom does the 'main' function returns its value? Where does the value go, when its returned using the expression

```
return(0);
```

at the end of the program?

Comment: Typically, the OS makes it available to the parent of your process, (e.g. in `bash` go `./yourprogram; echo $?`

Comment: A return type of `void` is system-specific. Compilers are permitted, but not required to accept return types for `main` other than `int` -- and unless you're on a freestanding (embedded) implementation, there is simply no good reason to define `main` with a return type other than `int`. Just add a `return 0;` at the end -- or you can omit it if your compiler supports C99 or later. (Some C textbooks recommend using `void main()`. *Good* C textbooks do not.)

Comment: And `int main()` is better written as `int main(void)`.

Comment: Related question. What calls main? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469955/in-c-how-is-the-main-method-initially-called

Comment: In most cases, `/dev/null`

Comment: @leppie there's no `/dev/null` in Windows and many other OSes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [main() functions return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818888/main-functions-return-value)

Answer (score 4):

This is completely OS-specific, but usually the OS invokes a program by

1. Setting up the program's address space,
2. Creating a record of the new process somewhere in the OS internals,
3. Launching its own custom function, which calls `main` and stores the return value in the OS internals.

The function I'm referring to in (3) is often a good old fashioned C function that just jumps into `main` so it can capture the return value from `main` as if it were an ordinary C function (which it in fact is). Afterwards, it stores that value somewhere in OS-land so that processes that need to read the return value can do so.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "jumps into main" or "calls main"?

Comment: @glglgl I've usually seen this done by getting a function pointer that points into the binary image, then invoking the pointee. So... Kinda both?

Answer (score 4):

As already said, this is OS specific. In UNIX systems it looks something like this:

When you compile a program with gcc, it wraps a startup routine around your `main()` function. This routine calls your `main()` function and saves its return value. It then calls the `exit()` function (which your program might call as well), that does some general clean up. This function then again calls `_exit()`, which is a system call that tells the OS to save the returned value of your `main()` function in the process table (where meta information about your process is saved). As soon as another process calls `wait()` on your process id (PID), your returned value is given to the calling process and your process is removed from the table.

Look at this resource for more information: http://www.johnloomis.org/ece537/notes/Processes/process_environment.html

Comment: Nit-pick: it wraps a startup routine *around* main, *not* *visa* *versa*.

Answer (score 1):

> Where does the returned value for 'main' function go?

It is returned to the calling process.

On a POSIX compliant systems if the calling parent process were a C program it could at least retrieve the lowest 8bit of its child's return value by calling `wait()` or `waitpid()` after the child ended.

Comment: That's POSIX-specific. There's no `waid()` or `waitpid()` on Windows, for example.

Comment: Windows?-> Updated my answer ... @KeithThompson

Comment: How it gets there and how the parent process gets it is system specific.  Windows has a function to retrieve the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

most operating systems call main like this:

`exit(main(argc, argv, envp));`

Comment: Do *most* operating systems really have `envp`?

Comment: @KeithThompson i don't know. i know windows, dos, and linux do.