# Why main() function in c++ do not take any other return type other than int and void

Tags: c++, c, function, return-type

I am new to c++ and I was using code blocks . I found that main() function is not taking return type other than int and void . I tried other data type to return the value and the returned the value of the same data type used . It was giving me an error when i use return type other than void and int . I would really appreciate it if you could explain it to me.

Comment: it doesn't take void as the return type. And what's the point returning a non-integral type? [Where does the returned value for 'main' function go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25434850/995714)

Comment: Could you provide a code example with error code? It could better tell us what you want do accomplish

Comment: Hint: Who/what gets the value returned by a program that terminates? Even if you could return a string or an array or some class, who will get it and what would you expect "who" to do with it?

Comment: In order for an application to be _executable_ on a particular operating system, the former should conform to the OS definition of what the _executable_ means.

A programming language runtime abstracts the OS definition of _executable_ from the source code level replacing it with a language-level definition of _executable_.

In C/C++ it's a free function returning int or void and taking nothing or argc/argv as arguments. The reason they chose these particular signatures to support is because it naturally maps to the POSIX OS/application interface.

Comment: @bobah "Returning int or void" is possibly true of some compilers, but not of "C/C++". In both C and C++, the only portable definitions of `main` are those equivalent to `int main(void);` and `int main(int, char**);`. C in a hosted environment allows additional implementation-defined types for `main`.  C in a freestanding environment does not restrict the name `main`, if it is used at all.  C++ always requires the return type to be `int` (if used at all, since a freestanding environment might not require one).

Comment: @aschepler - I definitely learned couple of news from your comment, but my main point was that this all is _just_ a protocol between the application and the  language runtime, a “given”. Asking about why it is not something else is probably not of much practicality.

Answer (score 1):

The main() function return value is the [process exit status/code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) returned to the OS. Historically this exit code represents an integer with 0 meaning success (at least on Windows, DOS, and POSIX OS).

Comment: But if I have other data type like char and returned char type value. In this case what it will represent success or failure.

Comment: @user10433098 -- why would you want to return a `char` or some other type from `main()`? You have to return what your operating system is looking for. If your OS is looking for some other type, that is where the implementation-defined caveat comes into play.

Comment: @user10433098: `main` returns `int` because the language definition says so.  That’s what the runtime environment is expecting.  You do not own the interface to `main`, only its implementation.