# Win32 Application, Call custom class method before calling Windows stuff

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

**Context:**

I am trying to create a class that is the first to be called in a WIN 32 application... That class has a Setup method... I will then invoke the Windows class taken from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

*header*

```
class OSWindows : IOS
{
public:
    void Setup() override;
};
```

*cpp*

```
#include "OSWindows.h"

void OSWindows::Setup()
{
    // Calls the windows stuff...
}
```

**Question**

How do i stop the Win32 application from automatically running their `WinMain` method...

**Note:**

I'm trying to make a portable application... and thus don't want the app to just simply have the app call the windows stuff first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a C/C++ program how does the system (windows, linux, mac OS X) call the main() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332/in-a-c-c-program-how-does-the-system-windows-linux-mac-os-x-call-the-main)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am creating the application in Visual Studio 2013 :) . I am finding out how to see which compiler is being used right now.

Comment: Lots of code runs even before WinMain is called:  CRT initialization, global constructors, initialization code in implicitly-loaded libraries and DLLs.  Do you want to prevent all that as well?  It's not clear how skipping WinMain helps you achieve portable code, so it's not clear how to guide you.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that's good to know... I'm obviously just entering the world of pain... Good to know there's more to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can change the entry point at

`Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem`

If you want it to be `int main` change it to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`.
The default for Win32 Applications is `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` which is `WinMain`.

Comment: Very hard to see the connection between the question and this answer. Perhaps if this is the answer, then the question should be re-formulated.