# Don't open terminal window while opening SDL window on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, sdl

When opening a SDL program, double clicking on the icon, a terminal window pop up too. How can we avoid this ?

I saw that on Windows OS, there's a compilation option `-mwindows` which do this but it doesn't work on OSX.

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // SDL window
    SDL_Window* window(0);

    SDL_Event events;
    bool quit(false);

    // Initialize SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Initialization error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }

    // Create window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Windows", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if(window == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Creation error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }

    // Main loop
    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&events);

        if(events.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
            quit = true;
    }

    // Quit SDL
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my makefile :

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: clean, mrproper, run

NAME=Program

EXEC=$(NAME)
SRC_DIR=./Sources
HEA_DIR=./Headers
OBJ_DIR=./Objects
SRC=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))

HEA=$(wildcard $(HEA_DIR)/*.h)

FRA_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/

CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall -std=c++11 -I $(HEA_DIR) \
                             -I $(FRA_DIR)
LDFLAGS=-F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(HEA)
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o

mrproper: clean
    @rm -rf $(EXEC)

run:
    @./$(EXEC)
```

Thanks in advance

PS : sorry for the format of my makefile I didn't manage to change that !

Comment: Please show the smallest, simplest program that demonstrates the effect and also state how you compile/build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually really easy to do and has nothing to do with SDL or your build system.

**First an aside**

The proper way to accomplish this is to produce an "app bundle". There are plenty of existing questions/documentation on how to produce one. @Mark Setchell covers one such method in his answer.

If for some reason you wish to avoid an app bundle read on for how you can.

**What is actually happening**

When you double click an executable or an app it doesnt actually execute it. What happens is the path is passed off to [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services?language=objc) which will then check if something is an "app bundle" or something else. If it not an app bundle LS checks its database to see what application it should open it with. You can see (by using "Get Info" in Finder) in the case of a stand alone binary it is set to "Open with" Terminal.app. This is the reason Terminal opens when you double click your binary.

**How you change the behavior**

You need to convince Launch Services that what you are double clicking is an app bundle. The only thing you need to do is add the `.app` extension to your binary. That's it.

I just tested this on 10.13 by creating a new "Command Line Utility" in Xcode. I simply added a `.app` extension to it and double clicked it and it opened and ran just fine. I'm not sure if you might run into issues (aside from the obvious) with something that uses `stdin` or `stdout` (`stderr` seems to be routed to the system console)

You can even embed an `Info.plist` file directly into the binary via Xcode (Build Settings -> Packaging -> Create Info.plist Section in Binary) if you need one or just want a version or something to show in Finder.

**Restrictions**

There is a caveat however, if code signing is involved you cant just pull apart an existing app bundle to try it. The `@rpath` of a binary pulled out of an existing bundle linking to frameworks will need to be changed. Ditto any bundle resources.

As mentioned before you really have no `stdin` or `stdout`. An SDL application likely doesn't care since it will create its own UI; except for maybe logging which should be directed at the console anyway.

Comment: Any insights on the bluriness mentioned by OP?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the only difference I can think of between him opening via terminal and either of our methods is the environment. You can control that (and a great deal of other things) via entries in the `Info.plist`. I do not know what environment variable specifically would control that, but it is a separate question for OP to ask.

Comment: @BradAllred I couldn't imagine a simpler solution ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether there is a *"proper"* way to do this, but I compiled your program into a binary executable called `main` with:

```
clang++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2) -o main
```

Then I used `appify` from [here](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099), to make it into a regular *"app"*:

```
appify main "Mark App"
```

and when I double-click my shiny new `Mark App` it throws up an SDL window and no Terminal.

---

If you start `Xcode` and click `File`->`New Project` it will offer you the options of creating a *"Commandline tool"* or a *"Cocoa Application"*. I guess if you did that and created both types of application you could compare and see what the difference is in the files generated and do that, but I don't know myself.

Comment: The answers to this question give some insight into, and associated terminology for this stuff... https://stackoverflow.com/q/12332/2836621

Comment: Very nice trick ! I Didn't know it. Sadly, I test it on an other project (using OpenGL) and it didn't work with this one. An interesting thing for me was the blurred window it generates (at least on my computer). I sometimes encounter programs with windows blurred like that and this may be explanation.

Comment: If you'd care to supply some code that draws something in the window, I can see if it comes up blurred on my iMac...

Comment: That's nice. Actually, the code I posted above already appear blurred when I appify it. With OpenGL it's different, I used a test scene which draw a single triangle and in this case, the window show up (blurred and without terminal window again !) but the triangle doesn't appear.

Comment: making an app bundle is indeed the "proper way". for the improper way to accomplish this see my answer.